# Need to get field tid from taxonomy

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

[image: devel dsm]

Trying to retrieve tid from field_report_group in my module. I can not seem to be able to grab it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a variable containing the entire structure that you have added.

Try

```
$taxonomy['8942']->field_report_group['und'][0]['tid']
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the context you are loading the term (template or module) there may be more appropriate ways but a general one is to use:

[taxonomy_get_term_by_name](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_term_by_name/7) if you don't have the tid

[taxonomy_term_load](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_load/7) if you do have the tid

and
taxonomy_get_tree if you want to load the whole vocabulary

Comment: I am attempting to accomplish it in a module.

Comment: depending on what you have available to you, use the appropriate function (they are linked to their documentation page) dpm the new structure and go from there

Answer (score 0):

You should use `field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, $field_name);`